# In Powershell, how to run an executable for an hour, stop for half an hour, then repeat?

Tags: powershell

I have an executable at *"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\scraper\work.exe"* and I'd like to do the following in Powershell.

- Step 1: Run *work.exe* for an hour and stop
- Step 2: Wait for half an hour
- Repeat step 1

I hope there is a clean and simple solution. I have looked at *Start-Process* and *Wait-Process* with no success. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start the process and grab the PID, then use that to stop it later.  This will do what you asked forever (while 1).

```
While (1) {
    $proc = Start-Process C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\scraper\work.exe -PassThru
    Start-Sleep -Seconds (60*60)
    Stop-Process $proc.Id -force
    Start-Sleep -Seconds (30*60)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Start-Sleep -s or -m`

```
[Exampe and usage][1]https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177002.aspx
```